# Ordering a rails model with string outline notation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a rails model that the primary field that the user wants to sort on is a Line Item that is stored in dot-notation format as a string (i.e.: `2.1.4`, `2.1.4.1`, `2.1.4.5`, etc). Ordering alphabetically works great, except that `2.1.4.10` comes before `2.1.4.2` alphabetically. What I want to call 'dot-based numeric order' would put `2.1.4.10` after `2.1.4.9`, and `2.4.1.10.1` would precede `2.4.1.11`

The question is this: What is The Rails Way™ to set the default order on the model so that the Line Items appear in the correct order, according to 'dot-based numeric order'.

Presume a simple case:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :line_item, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

and that :line_item is a string.

Comment: I am using postgresql.

Comment: @JosephFreivald I updated my answer, I think it will solve your problem :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I overrode the `<=>` operator with @Penne12's code:

```
  def <=>(y)
    self.line_item.split('.').zip(y.line_item.split('.')).inject(0) do |res, val|
      (res == 0)? val[0].to_i <=> val[1].to_i : res
    end
  end
```

Sorting works on any enumerable collection, with no sort block:

```
bobs_items = LineItem.where(:owner => bob, :complete => false)
"Bob's workload: #{bobs_items.sort.map { |li| li.line_item }.join(', ')}"
```

Comment: This still sorts things the exact same way (there is no performance benefit) - just behind the scenes. It's normally best not to override an operator like that. Also, it's always best to use a more descriptive method name. Although it works, it's not a good way, and will probably give you more problems along the way, especially if you end up needing to sort by something else.

Comment: Why is it bad to override the operator? Sorting it before only sorted it alphabetically, which wasn't helpful at all. My understanding is that I can provide a block to sort if I don't want this, but 99% of the time it will sort on the line item only, so there is benefit in making the general case easy, no?. I'm less concerned with the performance than functionality at this point. Interfacing with the spreadsheet output and what-not is over 80% of the processing time. Database access and sorting is way down on the list (< 2%)

Comment: It's really the operator, and not the sort function - when you override the operator, you won't be able to sort by anything else - even if you pass a block, you'd have to override/rewrite the code to compare the 2 objects - it'll end up creating a bunch of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using PostgreSQL and if you **really** want to set default order for your model, add this `default_scope` to your `LineItem` model:

```
default_scope -> { order("STRING_TO_ARRAY(line_item, '.')::int[] ASC") }
```

Otherwise I suggest you to use **named scope**, it can be override and chained:

```
scope :version_order, -> { order("STRING_TO_ARRAY(line_item, '.')::int[] ASC") }
```

Comment: The `cidr` implementation does not work because not all the items fit into the `inet_addr` conventions.  For example, `4.3.4.1.2` is not a valid IP address, so the `cidr` order throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

## To do this yourself:

```
lines = ['3.3.3.3', '3.54.3.3', '3.3.3.20']
sorted = lines.sort do |a, b|
    a.split('.').zip(b.split('.')).inject(0) do |res, val|
        (res == 0)? val[0].to_i <=> val[1].to_i : res
    end
end #=> ["3.3.3.3", "3.3.3.20", "3.54.3.3"]
```

## How it works:

To sort, we pass an array and a block, that blocks gives us 2 arguments that are next to each other in the list, and we can return 0, -1, or 1, which tells Ruby which directions to swap the numbers.

```
[4,3,-1,2].sort do |x, y|
  if x > y
    1
  elsif x < y
    -1
  else
    0
  end
end #=> [-1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Instead of doing that long logic, Ruby provides a nice operator for us: `<=>`. Zero means no change, -1 means it's in ascending order, and 1 means the two numbers are in descending order. Ruby repeats that a bunch, and sorts the list.

```
4 <=> 4 #=> 0
3 <=> 5 #=> -1
5 <=> 3 #=> 1
7 <=> -1 #-> 1
```

So, we should give higher items (in terms of dots) priority:

```
#Pseudo Code:
33.44 > 22.55 #=> true
33.44 < 44.33
```

The easiest way to integrate through all the numbers is an `#inject`, which gives you a value, and the item you are on. You can do things like this:

```
[4,4,4].inject(0) {|sum, i| sum + i} #=> 12
[4,4,4].inject(0) {|sum, i| sum - i} #=> -12
['Hello', "I'm penne12"] {|new_word, word| new_word + "-" + word} #=> "Hello-I'm penne12"
```

So, we'll use an inline if:

```
(true)? "it's true" : "true is now false. Yay!" #=> "it's true"
(4 > 5)? "logic is weird" : "4 > 5" #=> "4 > 5"
```

Like this:

```
.inject(0) do |res, val|
    (res == 0)? val[0].to_i <=> val[1].to_i : res
end
```

We'll split both strings by the `.`, to get a list:

```
"Hello. This. Is. A. Test.".split('.') #=> ["Hello", " This", " Is", " A", "Test"]
"4.4.4.4" #=> [4,4,4,4]
```

And join the two lists together by element using ruby's `#Zip` (it's really weird.)

```
[4,4,4,4].zip([5,5,5,5]) #=> [[4,5], [4,5], [4,5], [4,5]]
```

You can change what item a and b are, if you want to sort by a different property. Ruby doesn't care what you do to either variable, it only cares about the return value.

```
a, b = a.line_item, b.line_item
```

## On a model:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :line_item, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  def self.sort_by_dbno
     self.all.sort do |a, b|
       a, b = a.line_item, b.line_item
       a.split('.').zip(b.split('.')).inject(0) do |res, val|
         (res == 0)? val[0].to_i <=> val[1].to_i : res
       end
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the 'DIY' option as a named scope, or would that have to be done as a function in the database?

Comment: @JosephFreivald Just make a method on the model, the only bad thing is you can't chain them, but it should work fine.

Comment: Also, to change the property to sort by, change a and b in the sort block.

Comment: If I put a method like `sort_by_line_item` on the model, what do I put as the parameters so that it will sort a collection, and how do I call it? All of the tips I find on overriding sorting just use simple scopes, not with custom methods.

Comment: Define method as `self.sort_by_line_item`, and use `ModelName.all` to get your list, you can then apply scopes to that. I'll post an example soon.

Comment: @JosephFreivald Added an example.

Comment: nice, what if we have 1 million objects?

Comment: @antiqe no better way to do this really. Suffer through it?

Comment: @panne12 it is better to do it through SQL

Comment: I've used a portion of your solution to get something working, and I will look into the rest when I get a breather.  I put a method on the model like this: 
`def sort_by_wbs_line_item(a,b)
    return 0 if b.nil?
    a.line_item.split('.').zip(b.line_item.split('.')).inject(0) do |res, val|
        (res == 0)? val[0].to_i <=> val[1].to_i : res
    end
  end`
and then used `@li_collection.sort { |a,b| a.sort_by_line_item(a,b) }` to put them in order.  This works perfectly, but doesn't 'feel' right.  I'll select a solution in a day or two when I can try your and Long Nguyen's solution.

Comment: I really appreciate the tutorial on <=>. I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: I found a way to make this work without having to have a sort block.  See my response.

Comment: @JosephFreivald I released that I was wrong on the fact that you can't chain scopes to methods like that - turns out `all` will respect scopes you've applied, so you can change stuff (`user.line_items.where(some_attr: "a value").sort_by_dbno` will work as you'd expect)

Comment: I got that. Thank you. Users will never work with `all` the line items because they span projects. They are always working with subsets. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JosephFreivald A `has_many :through` relationship would be really nice there, then. (On the user `has_many :line_items, through: :projects`)

Comment: Yeah, I simplified the example to focus just on the sort issue. The actual schema has over 50 tables, with multiple types of line items that can be inter-related, like Performance Work Statement to Work Breakdown Structure, and/or Request for Proposal, etc., and they are related to Projects through tasking, accounting, and billing to Contract Line Items, all with labor hours according to category, sub-contractor and skill category and materials. The list goes on. :)

Comment: @JosephFreivald try single table inheritance - you might be able to dry out some code, if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into it.